# NHibernate to return Dictionary <int, string>

Tags: c#, nhibernate, dictionary

Is it possible to return Dictionary`<int, string>` from an nhibernate query such as this:

```
CreateQuery("select CustomerId, FullName from Customer")
```

I've tried a few examples from this forum using the .net ToDictionary method, but am unable to get them to work.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do the following on your list or enumerable and you should get the dictonary

```
.ToDictionary(x => x.CustomerId, x => x.FullName);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any way how to do this directly in NH. `ISession` does not provide it, `ICriteria` neither. `IResultTransformer` just converts simple entities and lists of entities to lists.

Of course there is workaround:

```
CreateQuery<Customer>("select CustomerId, FullName from Customer")
.ToList<Customer>() // since now working on real objects
.ToDictionary(x => x.CustomerId, x => x.FullName)
```

However, this is not ideal since you convert results to list just to be able to convert it to dictionary. So there is one additional transformation degrading performance.